# Android Google Maps only partialy starts

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I am trying to get Google Maps going in the emulator. I was able to start code on the actual device but emulator is a different story.

I am trying to use emulator with Google API 18 for that. My minimum SDK is 15 though.

All I got in emulator is an empty screen with +/- controls in the bottom write corner.

When my map runs I get following messages in Logcat.

```
09-30 12:35:27.761: ERROR/Google Maps Android API(1327): Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above 
09-30 12:35:28.441: WARN/EGL_emulation(1327): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 
09-30 12:36:16.741: ERROR/CheckinTask(550): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): java.net.SocketTimeoutException   
09-30 12:37:01.003: ERROR/CheckinTask(550): SSL error, attempting time correction: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x2a2d2368: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
            error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0x59bf16ba:0x00000000) 
09-30 12:38:01.201: ERROR/CheckinTask(550): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): java.net.SocketTimeoutException    
09-30 12:38:17.482: WARN/Uploader(545): No account for auth token provided 09-30 
12:39:10.121: ERROR/CheckinTask(550): SSL error, attempting time correction: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x2a2daaa0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
            error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0x59bf16ba:0x00000000) 
09-30 12:40:10.381: ERROR/CheckinTask(550): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.Mapper"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
          android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_GENERATED_KEY_IS_HERE"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Activity code is as following

```
package com.example.Mapper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w("........................","................................................");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Integer resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MyActivity.this);
        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        } else {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, MyActivity.this, 0);
            if (dialog != null) {
                //This dialog will help the user update to the latest GooglePlayServices
                dialog.show();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I don't understand why there are no SSL errors on the device and there errors when I use the emulator. Please assist.

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer,  the emulators are not designed to be able to run Google maps. Though if you install the latest Google services apk, you might anyway. Last time I tried it did not work, but have had it running.

Comment: Google says that emulator do support maps. Requires AVD running API 17

Comment: Ok, changed since I used it then

Comment: Did the Google Maps app that is included in the Google APIs AVD run correctly in your emulator? Also, check whether the date/time settings on your emulator is showing the current time.

Comment: Date is right. Time is off by an hour but I think it has to do with the time zone. I have not tried to run example app as I am trying to run a basic example of the Google developer web site. All I am getting so far is " ERROR/Google Maps Android API(1201): Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above" error

Comment: I was referring to the official [Google Maps app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en) included in the AVD, not the example app. If that runs fine, it will at least confirm that your emulator can connect to Google's servers without problems. Please also check the timezone settings in the emulator since incorrect time will affect the SSL communications.

Comment: Default Google Maps app in the AVD works. I have reset to my time zone. Still no luck.

Comment: I just tested this myself and am getting the same results. Apparently this is a confirmed issue by a project member at Google: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to Genymotion emulator and my problem has disappeared. The issue was not that I was doing something wrong but rather with GOOGLE's emulator.